# ABP Add Migration Issue

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

When trying to create a database migration, I am getting the following message:

Your startup project doesn’t reference Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design.  This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' package in 'xxx.EntityFrameworkCore' project, as example:

https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/66bf545d1fa1a696b0680ebdd4684d5faec8f1d3/BookStore-Mvc-EfCore/src/Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore/Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj#L24

'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' includes 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' package:

[image: Image example]